# Create dictionary from csv with only all data in only 1 column

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I've looked for a long time for a similar problem but couldn't find one.

When I open a certain csv file with Excel the data for each row is packed together in one cell separated by ";" instead of multiple cells. The first row is a list of strings and all other rows are integers. I would like to make a dictionary with Python using the first row (list of strings) as the header. The csv file looks like the following. I downloaded the file from a machine learning database [datafile site](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/)

```
     col1
row1 "x";"y";"z"
row2 1;2;3
row3 4;5;6
```

When I use the code

```
import csv

new_list = []
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        new_list.append(row)

print(new_list)
```

I end up getting

```
{'"x";"y";"z"':'1;2;3'}
{'"x";"y";"z"':'3;4;5'}
```

instead of

```
{'"x"':'1','"y"':'2','"z"':'3'}
{'"x"':'4','"y"':'5','"z"':'6'}
```

How do I make a dictionary from this type of csv file? (When I have a csv file that opens in Excel where all data points have its own cell the csv.DictReader class has worked well to make the dictionary but it's not working with this type of format)

Comment: This question is confusing: is the `col1` part of your file? Is it relevant to the question? And is the `;` / `,` discrepancy a typo, or an actual part of your problem?  Also, what do you mean by "all data in one column?"

Comment: When I open the csv file ALL the data is in the first column. I think it's relevant because when I open other csv files where each data point has its own column I get a normal dictionary using DictReader. Yes, it's a typo. all data has ";" separating it. I've now edited it so it's correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have multiple columns actually.
The separator is the comma `,`

Use :

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
```

**EDIT :**

You could probably write your own code :

```
with open('myfile.csv','r') as f:
    headers = f.readline().split(';') # First line are headers
    for line in f:
        current_object = dict(zip(headers, line.split(';'))) # create a directory with headers and current line
        print(current_object)
```

Comment: Reimplementing a CSV parser doesn't sound like a great idea; you could just use Python's standard one after parsing the headers.

Comment: @Clément have you noticed that I provided both solutions ?

Comment: @Loïc just noticed that I couldn't get solution 1 to work using the reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter ";") way but it worked when I did the second solution. Does row1 being a list of strings and not one long string have anything to do with why I can't the first solution to work?

Answer (score 2):

Simply skip the first row of your file:

```
import csv

with open(file) as f:
    next(f, None) # skip first row
    new_list = list(csv.DictReader(f))


print(new_list)
```

Or, in a repl:

```
>>> s = """col1
... "x","y","z"
... 1,2,3
... 4,5,6
... """
>>> import io
>>> import csv
>>> f = io.StringIO(s)
>>> next(f)
'col1\n'
>>> list(csv.DictReader(f))
[{'y': '2', 'x': '1', 'z': '3'}, {'y': '5', 'x': '4', 'z': '6'}]
>>>
```

Comment: I tried the code for skipping the first row and it returned all of row 2 as the key and a different row as a value. Don't I want to keep the first row for my keys?

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas library:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

txtfile = u"""col1
"x","y","z"
1,2,3
4,5,6"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txtfile),skiprows=1)
df.T.to_dict().values()
```

returns:

```
[{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}, {'x': 4, 'y': 5, 'z': 6}]
```